# Which is the shortest way to silently ignore a Ruby exception

Tags: ruby, exception

I'm looking for something like this:

```
raise Exception rescue nil
```

But the shortest way I've found is this:

```
begin
  raise Exception
rescue Exception
end
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Just wrap the left-hand side in parenthesis:

```
(raise RuntimeError, "foo") rescue 'yahoo'
```

Note that the rescue will only happen if the exception is a *StandardError* or a subclass thereof. See http://ruby.runpaint.org/exceptions for more info.

Answer (score 39):

This is provided by ActiveSupport:

```
suppress(Exception) do
   # dangerous code here
end
```

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Kernel.html#method-i-suppress

Comment: +1 for the clean solution, but I prefer no-dependencies solution.

Comment: I would suggest replacing `Exception` for `StandardError` since [it's not a good practice to rescue `Exception`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10048173/why-is-it-bad-style-to-rescue-exception-e-in-ruby).

Comment: clean? it's the dumbest method ever in my opinion, it rewrites the same thing in another way but it's not even shorter than a simple `rescue Exception; end` in most cases

Comment: Shorter is not always better. In this case the intention is much clearer than scrolling to the end of the block and seeing the "rescue end".

Answer (score 28):

```
def ignore_exception
   begin
     yield  
   rescue Exception
   end
end
```

Now write you code as

```
ignore_exception { puts "Ignoring Exception"; raise Exception; puts "This is Ignored" }
```

Comment: Note (because I misunderstood at first): This "ignores" the exception in the sense that everything continues after skipping the rest of whatever is between the begin and the rescue the exception. What it *doesn't* do is entirely ignore the exception in the sense that it continues doing what it was doing between the begin and the rescue.